# nth-child and nth-last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having an interesting situation here, 3 examples

1 - This is default for all, overridden by the below CSS.

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div/>
</body>
```

2 - This one fails to say If I am child 1 and I am 2 from the last child then add this class and if I am the 2nd child and I am the final child, add this class.

```
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 49%;
    background: green;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div/>
    <div/>
</body>
```

3 - Example 3 performs as written, it notices that there are indeed 3 divs and appropriately assigns the correct width for the divs.

```
div:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(3),
div:nth-child(2):nth-last-child(2),
div:nth-child(3):nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 33%;
    background: purple;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div/>
    <div/>
    <div/>
</body>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: conditional css, if 1 div is in the body it takes 100% of the width, if 2 give each ~ 49% if 3, 33%..

Comment: That's currently not possible in pure CSS. You could use JS. You might also want to look at LESS/SASS.

Comment: Something this simple really should be though! Shoot, thank you for your input, I will go back to the drawing board and regig some JS. thank you

Comment: If you know the amount of divs in the parent you can use the `:not` selector to do what you want

Comment: Try out flexbox! http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for all the comments guys, I recoded a portion of the JS to get the CSS doing what I wanted, I will check out LESS/SASS flexbox!

Comment: It works fine in Chrome now. http://jsfiddle.net/umtkutyb/1/

Comment: Did you use exactly this syntax (`<div/>`) in the HTML file?

Comment: I can confirm the fiddle is working in IE 11. Sounds like CSS finally got fixed! Voting to close the question. @IlyaStreltsyn I am assuming you are picking me up on quick closing `div` is not valid HTML any more :)

Comment: @John, yes, for any HTML parser 'quick closed `div`' is nothing more than unclosed `div` with stray `/` character, and so it always has been. It's completely valid X(HT)ML though, but in browsers it works only for documents served with `Content-type`s like `application/xhtml+xml`.